# Way to get id of saved entity in Hibernate Interceptor

Tags: java, hibernate, interceptor

onSave() event occured before entity is saved, so entity doesn't have it's id. Is there any way to  get entity id AFTER saving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I was need to get filled entity. When we add entity to collection (e.g., HashSet), this entities changes own state during interceptor lifecycle. So, I just added entity to HashSet and then in afterTransactionCompletion() get entities from HashSet. Entity was fully filled and has an Id.

Answer (score 0):

As per JavaDocs of EmptyInterceptor, the onSave method receives "id" as parameter.  See here:http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/EmptyInterceptor.html

So, you can use that id value.

I am assuming you have created interceptor similar to the way explained here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html