# JPA auditing and capturing autogenerated IDs

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, audit-logging

I am looking for a proper solution for capturing the autogenerated ID after a DB insert with the use of the **AuditInterceptor** (that extends **org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor**).

The way it works is when the **EntityManager.persist(entity);** call is made, the **onSave** method of the **Interceptor** gets called prior to the new entity being persisted. The **entity** object is available to the **Interceptor** but it does not yet have a value of the autogenerated ID thus we end up logging a blank value.

After the transaction is completed the  **afterTransactionCompletion(org.hibernate.Transaction tx)** method of the **Interceptor** is invoked. My approach was going to be to add logic to this method to go back to the database and look up the last inserted autogenerated ID which is not desirable. Is there a more conventional way of getting the autogenerated ID available to the **Interceptor**?

Comment: Not very [conventional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17584352/2541560), but how's that for a duplicate?

Comment: Why not simply use a `@PostPersist` listener?